# dovecot: how to auto-create submailboxes

Tags: dovecot

I have some mailboxes automatically created by dovecot, such as Junk, by editing 15-mailboxes.conf:

```
mailbox Junk {
  special_use = \Junk
  auto = subscribe
}
```

I would like to add a submailbox.  I have tried:

```
mailbox Junk.learn-spam {
  special_use = "\Confirmed Spam"
  auto = subscribe
}
```

But this doesn't work (also tried '/' as separator).  Is this possible?  How can I implement?

Comment: You can define the separator in the config itself in `10-mail.conf`, parameter `separator`. First look up, what it is set to.

Comment: @sebix, setting `separator = '.'` did not change the behaviour.

Comment: I should point out that `doveadm mailbox create Junk.learn-spam` creates a submailbox 'learn-spam' below 'Junk'.  So it does appear I am using the correct separator.

Answer (score 1):

I found the problem.  The special_use attribute must be one of All, Archive, Drafts, Flagged, Junk, Sent, and Trash.  But it's not needed to define the mailbox.  I simply removed it:

```
mailbox Junk.learn-spam {
  auto = subscribe
}
```